# Postgres Query to match column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Need help in identifying the matching records and filter out.

Input :

| field1 | field2 |
| --- | --- |
| test_data | test data |
| test_data | test_data |
| test_data | test_data |
| test_data | test_data |
| test_data | test_da |
| test data | test_data |

Output:

Need query to create a query and identify only those records that are not matching :

I have tried below query:

```
select *
from test.table  
where lower(trim(field1))!=replace(lower(trim(field2)),'_',' ') 
  and lower(trim(field1))!=lower(trim(field2))
```

I am getting the output but I need to check if there is any other query that experts can help and works better.

Comment: Your attempt of replacing doesn't look right to me: Semantics are `REPLACE(input, search_string, replacement)` – if you have underscores in `field1` and want to match strings with spaces against you'd rather try `REPLACE(..., ' ', '_')`. You wouldn't need the second condition either this way.

Comment: Or if you want to match *any* combination of spaces/underscores against each other you might replace in both fields.

Comment: Please add another table to your question that shows the intended result for this sample data.

Comment: Agree with @JonasMetzler – and include for current table for `field1` combinations with `test data` as well *if* such one might be contained.